# When to delete copy constructor and assignment operator?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy, singleton

I am often seeing such (simplified) code:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) :a{a} {}

    A(const A&) = delete;
    A& operator=(const A&) = delete;

private:
    int a;
}
```

Then, throughout the program, the class A is instantiated only once.

What are the practical reaons to delete a copy constructor and `operator=` and at the same time **not** make the class Singleton?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and when delete copy constructor and operator=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291938/why-and-when-delete-copy-constructor-and-operator) or [When to delete copy constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367446/when-to-delete-copy-constructor)

Comment: Consider `std::thread`, which represents a single thread. There can certainly be multiple threads, but what would be the semantics of copying a thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When to delete copy constructor and assignment operator?

Copy constructor (and assignment) should be defined when ever the implicitly generated one violates any class invariant.

It should be defined as deleted when it cannot be written in a way that wouldn't have undesirable or surprising behaviour.

Probably the simplest example is the class `std::unique_ptr`. As the name implies, it has unique ownership of a pointer value. Copying the internal pointer would violate the invariant of unique ownership. That's what the implicit copy constructor (and assignment) would do. But there is no reasonable alternative either. Maybe you could implement a copy constructor that dynamically allocates a new object, and copy-initialises it from the originally pointed object. But then this pointer would have different behaviour from normal pointers whose copy will not cause allocation or creation of new pointed objects, which may be surprising and undesirable. Furthermore, `std::unique_ptr` needs to also be usable with pointed types that themselves might not be copyable.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a class that have vars allocating dynamic memory and you don't want to make a suitable copy ctor and cpy assignment operator to allocate a new memory to avoide having two pointers pointing to the same thing, you can delete the whole cpy ctor and cpy assignment operator.

If you want to disallow passing the object by value, you may delete them too.